# Проблема при настройке NTLM-авторизации (mod_authnz_sspi) Apache 2.4 Windows

Tags: php, apache, auth, ldap, ntlm

Использую mod_authnz_sspi для авторизации через Active Directory для сайта в интрасети.
Условно сервер называется stat123prod.company.ru, в интрасети ему присвоен dns-url stat.company.ru.

httpd.conf настроил по инструкциям в Интернете.

Когда захожу на stat123prod.company.ru - все ок, авторизация проходит автоматически, никаких проблем.

Когда захожу на stat.company.ru - выходит окно с просьбой ввести учетные данные.
Вводишь учетные данные - все ок. 
Нажимаешь "отмена" - выходит ошибка 401, потом обновляешь страницу - авторизация происходит.

Как сделать так, чтобы при использовании выданного "красивого" url с авторизацией не было затыков в духе окошка с просьбой ввести учетные данные?
Перерыл кучу сайтов, ответ не нашел.

Спасибо.

Comment: ip одна у обоих?

Comment: Да, IP совпадает.

Comment: если за место латиницы вбить цифры куда перекинет?

Comment: Результат как у  stat123prod.company.ru - выходит окно ввода учетных данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В-общем, решение нашлось.
Дело в том, что такая ситуация возникает, если браузер считает сайт не входящим в местную интрасеть. Следовательно, он считается недоверенным и это вызывает дополнительную аутентификацию.
Единственный способ это исправить - внести URL в список доверенных для интрасети компании (обычно с помощью системного администратора).
Несмотря на то, что в итоге IP один и тот же, браузер обращает внимание на URL. Это важный момент.
Протестировать можно на своем ПК, если есть привиления на редактирование списка доверенных адресов. Внести можно через IE.